# Listing all slugs?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, slug

I have a number of slugs and items in my custom category:

SLUG - number

video - 5 items

music -  5 items

[no-slug] - 5 items

empty - 0 items

blabla - 0 items

I want to list all non-empty slugs (otpionally with number of items next to them), like:

[ video (5) ] [ music (5) ] [ other (5) ]

(empty and blabla omitted)

Anyone knows how to do that?

All I know is how to get a slug for particular item:

```
<?php $slug = $terms[0]->slug; ?>
```

### UPDATE

My taxonomy registration:

#### functions.php

```
register_taxonomy("op", array("portfolio"), array(
  "hierarchical" => true, 
  "label" => "Categories", 
  "singular_label" => "Category",  
  "rewrite" => true,
));
```

#### page-portfolio.php

```
$taxonomy = "op";
function get_taxonomy_list_html($taxonomy) {
  $term_links = array();
  foreach(get_terms('Category') as $term) {
    if (!empty($term->slug) && $term->count>0) {
      $link = get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
      $term_links[] = "[ <a href='{$link}'>{$term->name}</a> ({$term->count}) ]";
    }
  }
  return implode(' ',$term_links);
}
```

Displays nothing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Wordpressor:**

Sounds pretty simple so I'm concerned I misunderstand, but in case I did understand correctly here's a function; just pass the taxonomy to it like this: `echo get_taxonomy_list_html('category')`:

```
function get_taxonomy_list_html($taxonomy) {
  $term_links = array();
  foreach(get_terms($taxonomy) as $term) {
    if (!empty($term->slug) && $term->count>0) {
      $link = get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
      $term_links[] = "[ <a href='{$link}'>{$term->name}</a> ({$term->count}) ]";
    }
  }
  return implode(' ',$term_links);
}
```

Comment: @Wordpressor: If this is the answer you need, please update your question to use the right terminology: you want to list all *terms* of your custom *taxonomy*.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - Good comment. I would have edited his title to be more clear if was certain that's if fact what he wanted. Hopefully he will make the effort to improve his title.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel, @Jan Fabry , this code doesn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong. I'm a bit confused with slugs and terms, but anyways I'm going to update the first post in a minute so you'll tell me what I do wrong.

Comment: @Wordpressor - When you say *"the code doesn't work"* can you be more specific?  That could mean many different things.

Comment: @Wordpressor -  As for *"slugs"* they are the lowercase version of your term's name.  If your taxonomy is `'color'` and it's slug is `'colors'` and your term's name is *"Red"* it's slug will be `'red'` and your URL for the posts linked to that term would be `http://example.com/colors/red/`. And hopefully you can tell from context that *"term"* refers to the thing with which you categorize a post and that has a slug and a name and an associated taxonomy.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel, check the first post, this code displays nothing. I don't know how to debug/be more specific on this :( Anyways thank you for explaining me the slug-thing.

Comment: @Wordpressor - I think I found the problem.  Try the updated code again.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel wow it works almost perfectly, doesn't display the rest of the items (uncategorized) but I'll figure it out! :)

Comment: @Wordpressor - Glad I could help! *(But don't forget my checkmark! ;)*

Comment: hi @MikeSchinkel, I've test your code against my installation. It does display links. However, when I follow the link, I got 404. Is there any problem I might have missed? I do have flushed the permalink.

Comment: @silent - Disable all your plugins and make sure your theme's `functions.php` file doesn't have any code to modify term links and it'll probably work correctly. You can then enable your plugins one-by-one until you find the culprit.

Comment: Hi, sorry. Forgot to followup. It's working correctly now, after changing slug from `types` to `product-types` and flush permalink.